# Why are items in my S3 bucket 403ing?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am uploading documents via the AWS API to an S3 bucket.  Works fine.

The items that are uploaded are marked as private though, so cannot be viewed online.  I can get around this by right-clicking the file in the Console and clicking 'Make Public', or by using the API to make it public.

Is it possible to make all files uploaded public, so I don't have to make additional API calls to do so?

The following is a screenshot of the bucket's permissions:

[image]

I don't *think* it's anything to do with IAM, as the requesting user isn't a user at all, it's the public.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done with a bucket policy (click bucket policy in your screenshot). e.g.,

```
{
  "Version":"2012-10-17",
  "Statement":[
    {
      "Sid":"AddPerm",
      "Effect":"Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action":["s3:GetObject"],
      "Resource":["arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket/*"]
    }
  ]
}
```

(see "Granting Read-Only Permission to an Anonymous User" on https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html)

That allows anyone (`*`) to perform `GetObject` on any item in the bucket, rather than having to set the permissions per-item.

Comment: Thanks - that has worked. However, AWS then shows a warning message stating they do not recommend ever allowing public access to a bucket.  If that's the case, what's the recommended method, as surely most s3 buckets are used for asset hosting of some kind?

Comment: afaik it's just a warning to stop people accidentally leaking private data. It would probably be better to put cloudfront in front of the bucket if you're using it for a website and need global distribution etc, and this would let you make the bucket private to your AWS account.